# Permission Denied Error in Next.js Application Docker Compose Setup

Tags: docker, next.js, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm facing a permission denied error when running my Next.js application with Docker Compose. The error message I'm encountering is as follows:

```
[+] Running 2/2
 ✔ Network nextjs-blog_default  Created                                                                                                                                         0.1s 
 ✔ Container nextjs-blog-web-1  Created                                                                                                                                         0.1s 
Attaching to web-1
web-1  | 
web-1  | > dev
web-1  | > next dev
web-1  | 
web-1  |    ▲ Next.js 14.1.0
web-1  |    - Local:        http://localhost:3000
web-1  | 
web-1  | [Error: EACCES: permission denied, unlink '/app/.next/build-manifest.json'] {
web-1  |   errno: -13,
web-1  |   code: 'EACCES',
web-1  |   syscall: 'unlink',
web-1  |   path: '/app/.next/build-manifest.json'
web-1  | }
web-1  | 
web-1 exited with code 0
```

This seems to be related to file permissions within the **`.next`** directory of my Next.js application. I believe it's occurring because of how Docker handles file permissions with the account `nextjs` in the file `Dockerfile`.

I create the Nextjs project at the link: https://nextjs.org/learn-pages-router/basics/create-nextjs-app/setup. The latest version of Nextjs is `14.1.0`

```
npx create-next-app@latest nextjs-blog --use-npm --example "https://github.com/vercel/next-learn/tree/main/basics/learn-starter"
```

If run by command `npm run dev` is normally.

My environment:

```
Ubuntu: 22.04.3 LTS
Docker: 25.0.2
Docker Compose: v2.24.5
```

Here's my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM node:18-alpine AS deps
RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat
WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json package-lock.json ./
RUN  npm install --production

FROM node:18-alpine AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=deps /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY . .

ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED 1

RUN npm run build

FROM node:18-alpine AS runner
WORKDIR /app

ENV NODE_ENV production
ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED 1

RUN addgroup --system --gid 1001 nodejs
RUN adduser --system --uid 1001 nextjs

COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next ./.next
COPY --from=builder /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY --from=builder /app/package.json ./package.json

USER nextjs

EXPOSE 3000

ENV PORT 3000

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

And here's my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  web:
    build:
      context: ./
      target: runner
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    command: npm run dev
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: development
```

Build image by command: **`docker compose build`** and run **`docker compose up`**

Could someone help me figure out how to properly handle file permissions in my Docker setup for Next.js applications? Thank you!

Comment: Your `volumes:` block is hiding pretty much everything that's in the image.  In particular, you try to `COPY --chown` the `.next` directory, but that ownership change is hidden by the bind mount.  Does deleting `volumes:` help here?

Comment: Yeah, you're right. And with that `Dockerfile` delete volumes and change command to `npm start`

Answer (score 1):

You can put the .next folder in a named volume to avoid this kind of issue

For example you can use this config for `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  web:
    build:
      context: ./
      target: runner
    volumes:
      - nextjs_cache:/app/.next
      - .:/app
    command: npm run dev
    ports:
      - "3001:3000"
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: development

volumes:
  nextjs_cache:
```

Comment: Wow, It works. Can you explain clearly in the detail?

Comment: When you're launching the container with the `docker-compose.yml` file, the mounted  files override the files inside the container. They do not belong to nextjs:node anymore. For example, my user is 1000:1000 on my computer and if I check the folder inside the computer the rights would be node:node and not nextjs:node as node is the user 1000:1000 user inside the container.

Answer (score 0):

The `volumes:` block hides everything in the image in the `/app` directory, which is to say, nothing in the Dockerfile has an effect.  Where you `COPY --chown=...` files into the final image in the Dockerfile, that's hidden by the bind mount, and you get whatever permissions the directory has on the host system.

Since all of the code is built into the image, you don't need this `volumes:` block at all.  You note in a comment that the image's `CMD` is also correct, and the target image is the final stage in the Dockerfile.  You should be able to trim the Compose file down to just

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
```